# How to get variable from .env file?

Tags: reactjs, api-key, .env

I'm trying to get my API Key from the .env file in my project using JS, but any way to import that I have tried so far hasn't worked. So far, I've tried

.env: `API_KEY="abc123"`
file: `const key = process.env.API_KEY;`

.env: `REACT_APP_API_KEY="abc123"`
file: `const key = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;`

.env: `REACT_APP_API_KEY="abc123"`
file: `const key = import.meta.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;`

.env: `VITE_REACT_APP_API_KEY="abc123"`
file: `const key = import.meta.env.VITE_REACT_APP_API_KEY;`

and nothing has worked. I'm importing the key directly into an html file inside a script tag, and I'm not sure if that would have an effect on the import or not. Hard-coding the key into the html file works fine; it only gets wonky on import. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Creating a `.env` file and trying to use its content won't just work. I believe this is not your case, but you don't provide much details to understand something else.

Comment: You can try installing dotenv

Comment: Don't use quotes... it is like that API_KEY=abc123